# Kube-Reserved/System-Reserved vs Eviction Threshold

Tags: kubernetes

I'd like to properly prepare our self-managed clusters for resource pressure scenarios. From the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reserve-compute-resources/) I cannot understand the need for configuring the `--eviction-hard` parameter, when we can achieve the same effect by setting up proper values via `--kube-reserved` for kubelet and `--system-reserved` for system daemons.

Let me ask through an example. Why would I need to set the reservations for Kubelet and system-daemons, when seemingly it would suffice to configure `--eviction-hard`? Whenever there's a resource pressure in general this should be enough to trigger a pod eviction event. So what's the reason for the existence of the options for Kubelet and system-daemons reservations?

Comment: I'd say that those options are to indicate how many resources are needed for Kubernetes components and system components. One thing that you can do with `--kube-reserved` and `--system-reserved` is to reserve the `CPU` needed for those components where the `--eviction-hard` is basing only on the memory and ephemeral storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per official documentation:

> #### Node Allocatable
>
> [image]
>
> 'Allocatable' on a Kubernetes node is defined as the amount of compute resources that are available for pods. The scheduler does not over-subscribe 'Allocatable'. 'CPU', 'memory' and 'ephemeral-storage' are supported as of now.

The `Node` allocatable (the resources that scheduler can use to allocate the workload) can be defined as:

- **`Node allocatable` = `Node capacity` - `kube-reserved` - `system-reserved`**

Also, as for:

- `kube-reserved`:

> `kube-reserved` is meant to capture resource reservation for kubernetes system daemons like the `kubelet`, `container runtime`, `node problem detector`, etc. It is not meant to reserve resources for system daemons that are run as pods. `kube-reserved` is typically a function of `pod density` on the nodes.
>
> -- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Tasks: Administer cluster: Reserve compute resources: Kube reserved](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reserve-compute-resources/#kube-reserved)*

- `system-reserved`:

> `system-reserved` is meant to capture resource reservation for OS system daemons like `sshd`, `udev`, etc. `system-reserved` should reserve `memory` for the `kernel` too since `kernel` memory is not accounted to pods in Kubernetes at this time. Reserving resources for user login sessions is also recommended (`user.slice` in systemd world).
>
> -- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Tasks: Administer cluster: Reserve compute resources: System reserved](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reserve-compute-resources/#system-reserved)*

**In short**, you can easily imagine what would happen when you do not reserve enough resources for system components and the `Kubelet`.

You can even come to the situation where the eviction handler will not come to play because the system will already go into unstable state.

Also worth to mention that:

> One thing that you can do with `--kube-reserved` and `--system-reserved` is to reserve the CPU needed for those components where the `--eviction-hard` is basing only on the memory and ephemeral storage.

Comment: Hello @BernardHalas. Does this [answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Comment: I would understand the the above does not answer the question, since I was trying the same problem. Isn't the above documetion explaining that --system-reserved will be used only at pod scheduling? How does it affect evictions and runtime usage of the memory on the pod?